# Absolute/fixed position: preventing items scrolling

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to figure out absolute/fixed positioning in CSS to put a logo at the bottom right of a webpage and have it stay there, even if the page content scrolls.  I've half achieved this, but now need to stop the logo moving too high up the page if the browser window is small.

I've created a drawing and brief notes of how I want it to work, and put them at the following link as a pdf:

[Click here](http://www.garywood.me.uk/test/Logo_problem.pdf)

Can anyone help me, please?

Gary

Comment: Wow - that was quick, thank you!  The CSS is just sets a div as:
position:fixed;
left: 720px;
bottom: 0px;

Answer (score 2):

So, the logo should be `position: fixed`, but *only* if the viewport height is larger than a predefined minimal value. You can achieve that with media-queries:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 300px) {
    #logo {
        position: fixed;
        /* your other styles */
    }    
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KC3UU/show/light/ (reduce the browser window height until the image collides with the gray DIV)

Comment: Nice. What about Browser compability?

Comment: @Stefan All except IE8/7. However, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for IE.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - thank you so much for this.  I've got it working up to a point, but have two issues.  First, I need compatibility with IE7/8, but am not sure how to implement the polyfill.  I'm a bit of a novice with coding - could you possibly add it to your demo, so I can see how to do it?  Second, when the height is small, so the logo takes on an absolute position, it doesn't move down as I scroll.  Is it possible to make it do this?  (i.e. sort of make it fixed to the bottom again once the user scrolls down the page at least as far as it's absolute top position?).  Thanks again, Gary.

Comment: @user1392546 I think I know what you mean. However, the solution depends on the HTML structure and the existing CSS code. Please create a simple demo page, and I will enhance that page to make it work.

Comment: @Šime Vidas thanks for this.  I've put a demo page here: http://tinyurl.com/d8kv356.  I've also written a memo to clarify how I want this to work, which is here: http://tinyurl.com/cwzsj36.  Thanks again for your help with this - I'm looking forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: @user1392546 I'll look into this at the end of the day (in about 10h) - I have work to do now `:)`. Remind me if I forget.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - great, thanks.  I'm working now too unfortunately, but I'll look forward to seeing your ideas later tonight.

Comment: @user1392546 Is this OK? http://jsfiddle.net/3KgRw/show/light/ (I had to use JavaScript)

Comment: @Šime Vidas - this is perfect, thank you so much!  I'm amazed that you could do this so quickly!  I'm really busy at work for the next couple of days, but I shall try to integrate this into my site design towards the end of the week, and I'm sure I'll be back here with questions at that point. In the meantime, many thanks again for your work on this mate - much appreciated.

Comment: PS - I guess you like cats?! :-)

Comment: @user1392546 It's http://placekitten.com/ - a service for image placeholders. There is no placepuppies.com though, so I had no choice `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas :)  I've tried this in several browsers and it works perfectly, so thanks again.  I just have one small issue with Internet Explorer (7, 8 and 9).  In those browsers, when the window is smaller than the pink box plus the logo, the logo scrolls correctly, but it doesn't stop once it's entirely visible, as it does in the other browsers.  I hate to ask when you've done such a brilliant job already, but is there anything we could do about this?  It's so perfect in every sense otherwise.  Cheers, Gary.

Comment: @user1392546 Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3KgRw/2/show/light/ I changed the calculation a bit, and btw, I added `triggerHandler` to ensure that the logo position is correct on page load (before the visitor scrolls anything)

Comment: @Šime Vidas - thanks, this now works fine in IE.  When the window height is smaller than the logo, is it possible to make the image position absolute rather than fixed?  At the moment, if the window height is very small, it scrolls as I anticipated, until you get to its bottom, then it becomes fixed, so you end up seeing a little bit of the logo fixed in place as you scroll down the page.  I'm being very picky now, I know, but it's only because you've done such an excellent job and I want it to be absolutely perfect.  Don't worry if it's a lot of hassle.  Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user1392546 I don't know what you mean. Could you make a screen-shot of the issue?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - yes, sorry, it's difficult to explain.  I've tried to show what I mean with screenshots at the following link: http://tinyurl.com/6vpdxnk  It's difficult to explain when I can't actually show you the scrolling, so if this still isn't clear let me know and I'll make a short screencast.  Thanks again for your continued help.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - that's absolutely perfect.  Exactly what I wanted.  I really appreciate your help with this - thanks very much.  I'll integrate this into my site later in the week, and probably be back here when I get stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with just plain CSS. (At least without the use of some crazy CSS hacks). But with jquery that should be possible: http://jquery.com/
There are some sticky/fixed position plugins for jQuery out there like http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll
but i don't know how or if they are solving with the problem you are facing. Worst case would be that you have to write a script on your own. Hope this helped a little even if i wasn't able to provide some code. 
P.S. This here is basically the same question: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120302190313AAJhUIp

Comment: Thanks, Stefan and Šime Vidas - really appreciate your help with this.  It's been driving me mad for most of the day!  Looking forward to your demo, Šime Vidas...

Comment: PS - in case it helps, the top of the logo needs to never be higher than 450px from the top of the window.